# Full screen div disappears when declaring DOCTYPE

Tags: html, css

I have 2 testing divs that I have full screen, it works but then as soon as I declare  it shrinks and doesn't display full screen.

I am trying to have the first div full screen and then scroll down to a second div that is also the size of the screen.

I set up a JSFiddle over at http://jsfiddle.net/ZfmMv/

The HTML Code:

```
<div id="home">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<div id="about">

        <h1>About</h1>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#home {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: aqua;
}

#about {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ff0085;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZfmMv/2/)**

Comment: should also add `margin:0;padding:0`

Comment: An explanation of what happens in browsers with different doctypes can be found in the following articles: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html, http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html, and http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/